# Can I fork GIT (version control system core) source and change it?

Tags: git, open-source

Can I fork GIT (version control system core) source and change that to have my special version control? Additionally, Can I sell the final changed source or service as a commercial product?

Comment: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yes and yes, but you need to make the source code of/with your changes available to the user of your fork.

Comment: That is so better if mention about the negative point.

Comment: @user3528438 this is the exact bottleneck :) So is the GitHub source code available to the public or not?

Comment: @user1686 I didn't know about open source community on the Stack Exchange. Thanks so much.

Comment: Are you asking about Git source code or about GitHub source code? Those are very different things...

Comment: @user1686 I think GitHub source code was used Git source code and extend it. Am I wrong? Is it a different source code?

Answer (score 1):

[Git is licensed](https://git-scm.com/about/free-and-open-source) under the [GPLv2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Version_2) license.
See the FAQ here: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-2.0-faq.html

Your use is generally permissible, but there are obligations you will have to distribute source code, retain original licenses and notices, limits on fee for source access, provide credit to authors, etc. See the FAQ for more information. The degree to which your obligations will be determined will depend on your specific plans and business model.

You will have to determine what license you want to distribute under, and then determine if those terms can be met while bundling or producing derivative works of GPL software. GPLv2 is non-severable so you cannot entirely remove it, or eliminate your obligations under it.

From the FAQ:

> Does the GPL allow me to sell copies of the program for money?

> Yes, the GPL allows everyone to do this. The right to sell copies is part of the definition of free software. Except in one special situation, there is no limit on what price you can charge. (The one exception is the required written offer to provide source code that must accompany binary-only release.)

The place were you may have trouble is where you wish to implement a license that is more restrictive than the original license:
From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Copyleft):

> Copyleft
> The distribution rights granted by the GPL for modified versions of the work are not unconditional. When someone distributes a GPL'd work plus their own modifications, the requirements for distributing the whole work cannot be any greater than the requirements that are in the GPL.
> This requirement is known as copyleft. It earns its legal power from the use of copyright on software programs. Because a GPL work is copyrighted, a licensee has no right to redistribute it, not even in modified form (barring fair use), except under the terms of the license. One is only required to adhere to the terms of the GPL if one wishes to exercise rights normally restricted by copyright law, such as redistribution. Conversely, if one distributes copies of the work without abiding by the terms of the GPL (for instance, by keeping the source code secret), they can be sued by the original author under copyright law.
> Copyleft thus uses copyright law to accomplish the opposite of its usual purpose: instead of imposing restrictions, it grants rights to other people, in a way that ensures the rights cannot subsequently be taken away. It also ensures that unlimited redistribution rights are not granted, should any legal flaw be found in the copyleft statement.[citation needed]
> Many distributors of GPL'ed programs bundle the source code with the executables. An alternative method of satisfying the copyleft is to provide a written offer to provide the source code on a physical medium (such as a CD) upon request. In practice, many GPL'ed programs are distributed over the Internet, and the source code is made available over FTP or HTTP. For Internet distribution, this complies with the license.
> Copyleft applies only when a person seeks to redistribute the program. Developers may make private modified versions with no obligation to divulge the modifications, as long as they do not distribute the modified software to anyone else. Note that copyleft applies only to the software, and not to its output (unless that output is itself a derivative work of the program).[e] For example, a public web portal running a modified derivative of a GPL'ed content management system is not required to distribute its changes to the underlying software, because its output is not a derivative.
> There has been debate on whether it is a violation of the GPL to release the source code in obfuscated form, such as in cases in which the author is less willing to make the source code available. The consensus was that while unethical, it was not considered a violation. The issue was clarified when the license was altered with v2 to require that the "preferred" version of the source code be made available.

One Critical note: if you really want strong answers to your questions and input on what you want to do in specific situations, there is absolutely no substitution for quality legal advice. nothing a person on the Internet says means a darn thing when you are facing a well-paid corporate legal team, and the details of your plan matter, so consider either using a well established permissive license that is known-compatible with GPLv2, meeting all its obligations and limitations (so no one can fault you) or make an investment in legal representation.

Comment: Thanks so much, Frank. I need more study on the matter. I'll check this as answer after that.